# synctex and piped input

Tags: pdftex, forward-inverse-search

When we execute `pdflatex -synctex=-1 normalfile.tex` we can see that the first lines of the produced `normalfile.synctex` are

```
SyncTeX Version:1
Input:1:/path to current folder/normalfile.tex
...
```

But if we execute `cat "Très étrange.tex" | pdflatex -synctex=-1` the file `texput.synctex` have no data about the line correspondence in `"Très étrange.tex"`, which is logical because `pdflatex` have no idea about the input file name. Well it could use a default value (something like `intex` or `stdin`) for the missing input, like it does it for `jobname` as `texput`, but it seems that this is not the case.

**So my question is : When I use piped input can I tell `pdf(la)tex` to use some particular name as replacement of the missing input file when creating the `.synctex` ?**

Comment: I'm sure you have a valid use case, but I'm still wondering: if you have the actual file instead of some unnamed piped data (which you do, otherwise there is nothing to synctex to), why don't you call `pdflatex` on that file directly?

Comment: @Marjin I started to building [a small tool](https://github.com/kpym/latex-fast-compile) for my personal use, that manipulate the original source file before to pass it to `pdflatex`. So in place to compile the original file I use another file. But I want that the final `.synctex` refers back to the original file. For many reasons (speed, problems with files with spaces and accents in the names...) it will be better to directly pipe the modified file in place to save it (with modified name) and then adjust everything.

Comment: How about compiling the modified file directly (i.e., `pdflatex -synctex=-1 modified_file.tex`) and then change the `Input` line in `modified_file.synctex` back to the original name afterwards?

Comment: @Marijn This is what I'm doing now. But I want to simplify my workflow.

Comment: Isn't it possible to create a shell that modifies your input and saves it, and then calls on pdflatex with the saved filename?  Essentially what you are presently doing by hand, you should be able to place into a shell.  Of course, this suggestion has nothing to do with LaTeX and everything to do with shell language.

Comment: Is pdflatex strictly required? With lualatex you could register `find_read_file` and/or `open_read_file` callbacks and thus read from another file than you actually claim, i.e., `\input{file.tex}` uses `io.open("modified_file.tex","r")` internally.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's what I'm doing now, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. For me it's like a bug to be able to create a `.synctex` that is useless. If at least there was a name, it could have been changed.

Comment: @frafl This is interesting. But in my particular case it is not very useful, because I want to speed up compilation (by recompiling the header and watching for file changes), and `luatex` is not famous to have a very fast compilation time, and precomiled headers are not compatible with `fontspec` :(